# Replace the name of a file (without extension) for dir name in bash linux

Tags: linux, bash, replace

I have multiple files inside a directory. The files have the name "Output" (Output.txt, Output.csv, Output.tsv, etc) and I want to replace that name with the name of the directory. I have tried a few ways but can only replace the file name with the extension.
The following way didn't work:

```
nombre=${PWD##*/}

for f in Output*; do
    mv -- "${file%. *}" "$nombre"
done
```

Comment: `echo mv -- "$f" "${PWD##*/}.${f##*.}"`

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename` commandline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727288/12574):

```
$ ls test/
Output.csv  Output.tsv  Output.txt
$ rename -n 's!\./(.*?)/.*(\.\w+)!./$1/$1$2!' ./test/Output.*
rename(./test/Output.csv, ./test/test.csv)
rename(./test/Output.tsv, ./test/test.tsv)
rename(./test/Output.txt, ./test/test.txt)
```

Remove `-n` (aka `dry-run`) when the output looks satisfactory.